# Is there a Mathematica/Lisp link?

Tags: programming, interoperability

I'd like to start learning [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) as it sometimes leads to interesting answers on this site with concepts borrowed from this language, so I'm curious. As I already spend most of my programming time in Mathematica, is there a way to execute Lisp programs from the Mathematica frontend?

Same question for related languages, like [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) or [OCaml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_Caml).

Comment: I suppose you've seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5451304/695132  Are you looking for a way to run some other language from the front end or to call it from the kernel?

Comment: @Szabolcs: I guess what he wants is something like MathLink, but for Lisp.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes I was looking for something like in the answer of WReach. The link of rubenko seems to do this.

Comment: One possible appraoch is to use a Lisp that runs on the JVM (for instance, [ABCL](http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/)), and then get at Mathematica through J/Link.

Comment: @Pillsy I think your comment could be an answer even if it's not tested yet.

Comment: Of course, one possibility would be to implement a Lisp interpreter in Mathematica.

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at [SchemeLink](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~czhu/SchemeLink/).

Answer (score 11):

Clojure is often described as a "modern-day LISP" (hosted on the JVM) that offers strong support for multi-threaded code.

If the Clojure dialect of LISP is an option for you then you might want to investigate using the JLink-based interface to Clojure provided courtesy of this package: [Clojuratica](http://clojuratica.weebly.com/)

Regarding Haskell and OCaml, your best bet may be trying to access F# (which is closely related to Haskell and OCaml) through .NETLink.

Comment: Nice link, thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote but it seems clojuratica support has somewhat ended.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't actually tried this, but you might want to investigate using one of the Lisps for the JVM, such as [Armed Bear Common Lisp](http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/), and interface to Mathematica through J/Link.

Answer (score 5):

These pages contain related links about a lisp interpreter in Mathematica:
http://www.umcs.maine.edu/~chaitin/#LISP
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/729/
http://mathematics-diary.blogspot.fr/2011/10/limits-of-mathematics-or-lisp.html

Answer (score 1):

For creating this Common Lisp package, Richard Fateman was reportedly once threatened with a lawsuit by Wolfram:

https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1089419.1089421